# Applying a custom function to data from select columns if condition is met using apply and mutate_at

Tags: r, function, apply, dplyr

I'm trying to add a character to the front of select columns (those that end in "c") of a dataframe that are numeric and not blank/NA. I am approaching this using `mutate_at` to select specific columns and `paste0` to add the character to the front of the string but I am running into issues as it will as a character to every cell even if its blank/NA:

```
appendCoeff <- function(x) {ifelse(is.numeric(x), paste0("a", x) , x)} 
#appendCoeff <- function(x) paste0("a", x)
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate_at(vars(ends_with("c")), appendCoeff)
```

My question is do I need to incorporate `lapply` with `is.numeric` as an alternative? Data below for first 15 lines:

```
> dput(head(df2,10))
structure(list(Reaction = c("k1", "k2", "k3", "k2", "k3", "k4", 
"k5", "k6", "k7", "k8"), R1c = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), R1 = c("HOCl", "OCl-", "NH2Cl", "NHCl2", "H2O2", "HO2-", "NH2Cl", 
"NH2Cl", "NH2Cl", "NHCl2"), R2c = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), R2 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "$OH", "$Cl", 
"$Cl2-", "$OH"), R3c = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
""), R3 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), P1c = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), P1 = c("$OH", "O$-", 
"$NH2", "$NHCl", "$OH", "$OH", "$NHCl", "$NHCl", "$NHCl", "NCl2$"
), P2c = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1"), 
    P2 = c("$Cl", "$Cl", "$Cl", "$Cl", "", "O$-", "OH-", "Cl-", 
    "Cl-", "H2O"), P3c = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", 
    ""), P3 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "H+", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: column values. I was able to do it to the column names by accident using `rename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `is.numeric` is that most of the columns are `character` class except one of them with 'R1c'.  So, if we use `is.numeric` on a `character` column, it will return `FALSE`.  Instead, we can check whether the elements have only digits (`[0-9.]+`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string.  An easier option is `!is.na(as.numeric(.))` i.e when we use `as.numeric`, it converts the actual numeric values to numeric, while non-numeric will be `NA` and then we create the logic with `is.na` (but with a warning message)

```
library(dplyr)
libray(stringr)
df2 %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("c")), ~ case_when(str_detect(., "^[0-9]+$") ~
               str_c("a", .), TRUE ~ as.character(.)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this response! Successful! Can you explain how the "." works within the `str_detect` and `as.character` functions within `mutate` so I can learn to use it better?

Comment: @jbearazesh  WIth `~` it acts as a anonymous function you created `function(x)`  Here, by default, the `x` is `.` i.e the values of that column.  `case_when` is very particular about types.  It cannot mix one type with another.  If you check the first first `R1c` column, it is `double` while the others are `character`.  So, to make this to same type or else it fails, we have to change the column to `character` with `as.character`

Comment: @jbearazesh  Do you need to change the column name of 'R1c' ot 'Jan', 'R2c' to 'feb', etc?

Comment: Once again thank you for the clear explanation. I plan on converting these variables with numeric values of 1,2,3, respectively to use in an ordinary differential equation. If you had to assign values to these newly created strings knowing you want them as variables, would you use `assign` on  `varnames = c('a1', 'a2', 'a3')` , `eval(parse(`, or `do.call`. Trying to figure out the simplest way assuming the variables will increase from a1 to a240 not sequentially if that makes sense

Comment: @jbearazesh It is not clear from the comments.  Can you post as a new question?  Do you need to `spread` from 'long' to 'wide' format

Comment: Sure I will post a new question and link it here

Comment: New question asked. Its long-winded, and I am only looking for help in my methodology so I can understand how better to approach the problem. However, without explaining the full picture it was hard to convey the end goal. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107163/using-dplyr-and-conditional-formatting-to-construct-an-ordinary-differential-equ