# Using dplyr and conditional formatting to construct an ordinary differential equation from strings

Tags: r, apply, ode, dplyr

I am trying to create is a system of equations for a specific variable using `dplyr` and `prod` from a dataframe of strings to be used in an ordinary differential solver in R (`deSolve`). The location of the variable dictates the form of the equation and therefore I am using `grep`, `filter_at`, `mutate_at`, and `apply`.

Constructing the equation depends on the column of the string/variable of interest based off the following
i.

- If a variable is ever found as a product `(P1,P2,P3)` then multiply:  `+1 * Rate * R1c * R1 * R2c * R2 * R3c * R3 * (P1c or P2c or P3c)`
- What I am trying to convey with that last term `(P1c or P2c or P3c)` is that depending on where the variable is `(P1,P2 or P3)` then you
  need to multiply by the corresponding `(P1c, P2c, or P3c)`, but not all
  of them
- If  a variable  is found as a reactant `(R1,R2,R3)`  then
  multiply `-1 * Rate * R1c * R1 * R2c * R2 * R3c * R3`
- I then want to add everything together and set it equal to “dVariable”

  1. `dVariable = Sum(all product expressions) + Sum(all Reactant expressions)`

An example data frame that I have trimmed down is below.

```
structure(list(
    Reaction = c("k3", "k4", "k40", "k38", "k39", "k44"), 
    Rate = c("kHV_H2O2", "kHV_HO2-", "3", "27000000", "5500000000", "6600000000"), 
    R1c = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
    R1 = c("H2O2", "HO2-", "HO2$", "$OH", "$OH", "$OH"), 
    R2c = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1), 
    R2 = c(NA, NA, "H2O2", "H2O2", NA, "HO2$"), 
    R3c = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    R3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    P1c = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    P1 = c("$OH", "$OH", "O2", "HO2$", "H2O2", "O2"), 
    P2c = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1), 
    P2 = c(NA, "O$-", "$OH", "H2O", NA, "H2O"), 
    P3c = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), 
    P3 = c(NA, NA, "H2O", NA, NA, NA)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If we consider $OH as the species of interest, then:

- in Row 1 `$OH` is first found as a product in `P1` with a `P1c` of 2,
  therefore: `+1 * (kHV_H2O2) * (1) * (H2O2) *  (2)`
- In row  4 `$OH` is first found as a
  reactant in `R1`, therefore `-1 * (27000000) * ($OH) * (1) * (H2O2) *(1)`
- Lastly, combining the two as a new variable gives

  `d$OH = +1 * (kHV_H2O2)*(1)*(H2O2)*(2) - 1 * (27000000)*($OH)*(1)*(H2O2)*(1)`

My approach has involved converting everything to a string, assigning numerical values to those strings, filtering the data depending on if the variable is in a select column, and then multiplying those column together, and then converting to a formula.

```
#Set the Reaction variable equal to the Rate Constant.  
for (i in seq(nrow(df2))) assign(df2$Reaction[i],df2$Rate[i])

#Drop Rate from main data frame
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Rate= NULL)

#Find the unique chemical species 
  # Drop all numbers and constnats 
    Species <- df2 %>% mutate(
      Rate = NULL, R1c = NULL, R2c = NULL, R3c = NULL, P1c = NULL, P2c = NULL, P3c = NULL, Reaction = NULL)
  #Uniques  
    Species <- unique(as.data.frame(c(as.matrix(Species))), drop = FALSE)
    names(Species) <- "Species"
  # Omit N/A and unknowns
    Species <- filter(Species, Species != "unknown")
    Species <- na.omit(Species)

# create new variable for each unique species for deltatime Step
Species <- Species %>% mutate(
  DeltaSpecies = paste0("d", as.character(Species),sep="")) 

#Multiply Each Equation
nms <- grep("^R|^Reaction$|c$", names(df2), value = TRUE)
nms2 <- grep("^R|^Reaction$", names(df2), value = TRUE)

Prod <- function(x) paste(sub("^(.*[[:punct:]].*)", "`\\1`", na.omit(x)), collapse = "*")   # if the string contains, begins, ends with a $,-,+ then put it in ' '

#Match Products and Reactants
Products <- df2 %>% filter_at(vars(P1,P2,P3,P1c,P2c,P3c), any_vars(. %in% as.character(Species$Species[[16]])))
Reactants <- df2 %>% filter_at(vars(R1,R2,R3,R1c,R2c,R3c), any_vars(. %in% as.character(Species$Species[[16]])))


Reactants_final <- paste(apply(Reactants[nms2], 1, Prod), collapse = " - ")
Products_final <- paste(apply(Products[nms], 1, Prod), collapse = " + ")


Combine <- paste(Products_final, Reactants_final, sep = " - ")
Formula <- as.formula(paste(Species$DeltaSpecies[[16]], Combine, sep = " ~ "))
```

I am falling short on how to conditionally make the product expression without using unnecessary variables, assigning values to strings/variables, and extracting a usable formula with variables in the form `dX <- a*X + Y*Z`  to use in an ODE solver. I understand this is a long winded question, but I am just interested in tips to point me in the right direction to approach the problem (including exploring new functions). Would `eval(parse` be an approach to the problem to convert strings to variables, and assign values to them?

Comment: In the computation of the base reaction velocity, should it not be `base_vel = Rate * R1^R1c * R2^R2c * R3^R3c`? And then when you assign this to the differential increment of the substance `R1`, it gets the multiplicity as a factor to `-R1c*base_vel`, the same for a product `P1` of this reaction it gets multiplied with  its multiplicity to `+P1c*base_vel`?

Comment: Not exactly. The `base_vel`  would be `Rate * R1^R1c * R2^R2c * R3^R3c` and then if the variable is found in `R1,R2, or R3` we multiply `-1*base_vel` and if it is found as a product we multiply it by either `(+P1c,P2c,P3c)*base_vel` depending on if the variable is in `P1,P2, or P3`, respectively.

Comment: The biggest issue is handling converting all the individual strings into a useful expression to be used in an ODE solver. MY approach has involved `#df2$Reaction <- sapply(df2$Reaction, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`

Comment: One way would be to make a complete code translation, that is, your output is the derivative function for the system as code. This is then loaded and handled by `R` as separate script. Another sensible way would be to program or use some calculator library that can interpret a tape of bytecode of some type and translate the input into such a tape. Then each call of the derivatives function calls the calculator machine with the tape and the inputs and copies the output of the calculator into the derivatives vector.